# Equation with Exponential matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, transpose, matrix-exponential

I have the following equation:

\begin{gather}
(e^{At})^T \cdot P \cdot e^{At} - P = - I
\end{gather}

where im trying to find the matrix $P$.

Is there any name to this equation or some simple solution instead of breaking the matrices into each variable?

Thank you.

Comment: What is $T$, exactly?

Comment: $T$ that multiplies A is a scalar and T outside of the brackets denotes transpose. If I understand correctly it is connected to Lyapunov equation.

Comment: I edited your question to make $t$ (variable) and $T$ (for transpose) distinguishable.  Cheers!